# Unable to add 0.001 to REAL number

Tags: floating-point, plc, twincat

Here is minimal code in TwinCAT3

```
// declaration
fTest : REAL := 32700.0;

// implementation
fTest := fTest + 0.001;
```

The code will increase fTest up to 32768. The number won't be increased any more. Any current fTest value above 32768, will prevent increasing it. The number remains unchanged. Moreover, even if I change `0.001` to `0.0019`, `0.0011` it still won't increase. It starts increasing however, when I write `0.002`.

The `REAL` range spawns from `-3.402823e+38` to `3.402823e+38`. But there is something related to 32768. How can I properly add 0.001 or lower value to fTest above 32768? Could it be a bug in TwinCAT?

UPDATE:

More info about REAL in TwinCAT

> The structure of the 32-bit data type REAL according to IEC 61131 3 /
> IEC 559 / IEEE754 is 1 bit sign, 8-bit exponent to base 2 with sign
> (-126...+127), 23-bit mantissa (0...8,388,607).

Comment: Interesting, 32768 is two to the power of 15, that shouldn't affect floats but who knows what twincat is doing internally?  Also wtf is twincat? :-)

Comment: Which PLC are you running this on? Which TC runtime version?

Comment: @njuffa I've  update with more info about RELA.

Comment: @njuffa Could you please also put this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running into the limit what can be represented by the mantissa of 32-bit floating point numbers, which is about 7 decimal digits. This is not a bug, it is by design, and not related to TwinCAT.  Native floating-point arithmetic does not have arbitrary mantissa accuracy, it is a trade-off required for making it fast.

You might need to use an LREAL, which will still have limits, but would yield a result that should look like what you expect.

Please note that if you were to multiply or divide these numbers, the result would probably look OK to you. Floating point numbers being split into a mantissa and an exponent, hitting the limits depends on what the operation you are performing is, not just on the values involved.

The key is to remember that floating point numbers are not true real numbers, they are a rough approximation. In some cases "rough" translates to "totally unusable".  They are intended to yield similar, useful results very fast for most real-world cases dealt with in properly-coded software. But there are cases where not understanding and managing their limits may cause real problems, loss of money, damage to property, injury or death.

Answer (score 2):

[IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) [single-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has a precision limit of 24 binary bits.  And since it is a *floating* point format, the apparent resolution (that is, the precision to the right of the radix point) varies along with the magnitude of the number.

You can see this most clearly in decimal.  If we limit ourselves to 3 significant decimal digits, the numbers we can represent near 10 are:

```
 9.97
 9.98
 9.99
10.0
10.1
10.2
10.3
```

So we can represent 9.99, but we can *not* represent 10.01, and if we try, it is likely to round back to 10.0.

Binary floating-point is the same, except that it's all based on, as its name says, base 2.  So 32768 = 2<sup>15</sup> is one of the spots where the resolution changes.

Numbers just below 32768 require 15 bits for the integer part, so there are 9 bits available for the fraction.  Numbers just above 32768 require 16 bits for the integer part, so there are just 8 bits available for the fraction.

Just below 32798, the fractional resolution is 2<sup>-9</sup>, or about 0.00195.  Just above 32768, the resolution is half of that, 2<sup>-8</sup>, or about 0.00391.

So you can't actually represent all the numbers 32767.001, 32767.002, 32767.003, ... .  You're actually going to end up with more like 32767.002, 32767.004, 32767.006.  And in that light, it's surprising that you could get away with adding 0.001 at all!

You were saved, I think, by the fact that IEEE-754 requires *properly-rounded results* for all basic arithmetic operations.  And since 0.00195 is less than 0.002, adding 0.001 gets you a little bit more than halfway to the next number, so below 32768, you're always able to round up to the next representable number after adding.  But above 32768, the interval is closer to 0.004, so adding 0.001 only gets you about 25% of the way to the next one, so you keep falling back to 32768.

(Now, because we're dealing with base 2 here, your increment 0.001 isn't exactly representable, either, but that doesn't end up making much difference here.)

Putting this all together, here are the representable IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point numbers near 32768, rounded both to 3 and 6 places:

```
32767.994  32767.994141
32767.996  32767.996094
32767.998  32767.998047
32768.000  32768.000000
32768.004  32768.003906
32768.008  32768.007812
32768.012  32768.011719
```

Now, although this picture shows pretty clearly what's going on, it's misleading in that if you focus on the first column, it seems to suggest that the increment below 32768 is somehow exactly 0.002, and exactly 0.004 above.  But it's not, and we don't have to look far to see the characteristic sorts of discrepancies that always crop up when a signal frequency beats against a sightly different sampling frequency:

```
32767.977  32767.976562
32767.979  32767.978516
32767.980  32767.980469
32767.982  32767.982422
         ...
32768.016  32768.015625
32768.020  32768.019531
32768.023  32768.023438
32768.027  32768.027344
```

Those seemingly-random numbers after the decimal point are somewhat misleading also.  They're just six of the roughly 9 decimal digits required to represent the 9 or 8 binary bits that actually make up these fractions.  Here's one more version of the sequence, but with all 9 decimal digits shown, and a binary conversion also:

```
32767.992  32767.992187500   0b111111111111111.111111100
32767.994  32767.994140625   0b111111111111111.111111101
32767.996  32767.996093750   0b111111111111111.111111110
32767.998  32767.998046875   0b111111111111111.111111111
32768.000  32768.000000000  0b1000000000000000.00000000
32768.004  32768.00390625   0b1000000000000000.00000001
32768.008  32768.00781250   0b1000000000000000.00000010
32768.012  32768.01171875   0b1000000000000000.00000011
32768.016  32768.01562500   0b1000000000000000.00000100
```

The decimal digits may look semirandom, but the binary bits are clearly counting most regularly (just like the 9.99, 10.0, 10.1 decimal version I started this answer with).

---

That's the explanation of what's going on.  But your real question was, how can you fix this, and that depends on what you're ultimately trying to do.  If you truly want to work with (decent approximations of) the numbers 32767.999, 32768.000, 32768.001, you're definitely going to have to use something with better precision than single.  As we've seen, you weren't really getting increments of 0.001 below 32768, either.  Double precision, if it's available to you, would work much better:

```
32767.997  32767.9970000002
32767.998  32767.9980000002
32767.999  32767.9990000002
32768.000  32768.0000000002
32768.001  32768.0010000002
32768.002  32768.0020000002
32768.003  32768.0030000002
```

The decimal fractions still can't be represented exactly in binary, but at least the increments look correct.  (There is still the issue that you're not actually incrementing by 0.001, but it'd probably take billions of iterations before an actual discrepancy or "tear" showed up.  In general, though, performing repeated floating-point addition like this is a bad idea, for this reason.)